# Addition of Custom Keywords to .net to be addressed by a Pre or Post build process

Tags: c#, code-generation, keyword

I am looking for a method to add custom keywords to the .net framework that offer "special" pre-complier benefits or are ignored by the compiler.

Example I would like to do something like this

```
public static factory class Foo<T>
{
     public static create T Create();
}
```

I would like to add a pre-compile event that translates that code into functioning C#. 
I have already considered a few options (which I can not post here because I am limited to 1 hyperlink) none of them do exactly what I am looking to do. Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ? What will the meaning of these extra keywords be ?

Comment: It appears that my example may not illustrate all the situations when this would be used. Here is another example when working with the decorator pattern I would like to be able to have this syntax

public decorator class Foo2 : IFoo implementor Foo1
{
     public void Bar(){ Do Stuff; }
}

another example of this would be

public decorator class Foo2 : IFoo
{
     public Foo2(IFoo foo) : implementor foo

     public void Bar(){ Do Stuff; }
}

in these examples all methods except bar would be routed to either the constructor IFoo as passed in by a DI framework or an inner Foo1 reference

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done with the current C# version, unless you are willing to:

- Create your own C# compiler
- Create your own preprocessor to run before the actual compiler.

Comment: /agree, you may be able to get close with templating - suggest looking into T4 engine perhaps.

Comment: you mention "reprocessor to run before the actual compiler" I can not find any way to do this where I preserve the original cs file. The preprocessor event was my first thought. If you have an article or suggestion on how I can modify the cs file only for the compiler and not the original file that would be perfect.

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something more like this:

```
[Factory()]
public static class Foo<T>
{
    [Create()]
    public static T Create();
}
```

You can build your own attributes and should be able to use them to accomplish what you need here.

Comment: This is a good suggestion but requires implementation. The big thing I was trying to allow for is the decorator patter via deligation.

Example if you have an interface that has 40 methods but you only want to change one method, using a custom keyword i could fill in all the other method implementations. I am currently doing something like this in the code now with attributes but it requires the class be abstract then I emit the code at runtime to extend to the class. I then have a factory to get the extended version.

I would rather just handle it all at compile time if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Could you get away with just using annotations? Your example suggests you might, but I realize it could be misleading.

Comment: Annotations work well in my existing implementation but require a large price at startup of the application where I use codedom to create a new assembly at startup. I may move to a postsharper like model and just modify the IL but that will still not give me the compile time support I would like when it comes to code sense.

thank you for you suggestion